# Android application packaging

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I have two android applications- A and B.

I'm trying to package them as a single unit so that upon installation the system installs both apps. However, I could not find any reliable answer till now.

In A's manifest file I added activity tag of B, resulting in error.

Could anyone guide me on how to package two applications as a single unit?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible. An APK corresponds to a single `AndroidManifest.xml` which corresponds to a single Application.

However, if you want mulitple "launchers" or icons, it is possible by exposing multiple Activities by adding `IntentFilter`s to the ones you want (which take the launcher event). However, they are still, technically, a single application.

Update:
Here's how to expose multiple Activities. The main activity would have something similar in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Copy-paste this inside the other Activities you want to expose. For example:

```
<activity 
        android:name="com.example.app.FirstActivity" 
        android:label="@string/first_app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity 
        android:name="com.example.app.SecondActivity" 
        android:label="@string/second_app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the only way to do as far as I know. This gives a system (which is called an app in Android terminology) that aggregates several subsystems that can be seen as "sub-applications".

Comment: @sparkymat well, I'm quite a newbie into Android development. So could you please share a bit more on exposing multiple activities using IntentFilter?

Comment: Done. Do accept the answer if this has helped you. This is done by clicking the 'tick' below the votes beside the answer (in case, you were wondering :) ).